# Adding an int to an existing array of its

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Here is my code I have tried

```
int[] WeeklyTotal = new int[53];
for (int w = 1; w <= 53; w++)
{
    WeeklyTotal[w] = WeeklyTotal[w] + data.Rows[i]["week" + w];  // Error is here
}
```

But I'm getting a compile error:

> Can not apply opperator + to opperands of type int and object

What is the correct syntax here?

Thanks!

Comment: Also C# arrays are zero indexed, you need change `for (int w = 1; w <= 53; w++)` to `for (int w = 0; w < 53; w++)`

Comment: Instead of casting you could also use `DataRowExtension.Field`: `int weekValue = data.Rows[i].Field<int>("week" + w)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast `object` type to `integer` type

```
WeeklyTotal[w] = WeeklyTotal[w] + (int)data.Rows[i]["week" + w];
```

also your array iteration for loop logic needs to be updated otherwise index will be outside the range and it will throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`

```
for (int w = 0; w < WeeklyTotal.Length; w++)
{
    WeeklyTotal[w] = WeeklyTotal[w] + (int)data.Rows[i]["week" + w];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if the object really is a boxed integer use `(int)` Cast operator  else use    `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: Yes, `Convert` is a better alternative to cast in the context: `data.Rows[i]` can well return boxed `short` or, say, `String` (e.g. `"123  "`)  if database field is of wrong type etc.

Answer (score 1):

Need to cast object type as an integer:

```
WeeklyTotal[w] = WeeklyTotal[w] + (int)data.Rows[i]["week" + w];
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, you have to cast the `object` returned by `data.Rows[i]["week" + w]` to `int`.

But **more important** your `for` loop is buggy and will cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Arrays are zero-indexed in c#, so your loop should run from 0 to 52 or you have to decrease `w` by one when accessing the array:

```
int[] WeeklyTotal = new int[53];
for (int w = 1; w <= 53; w++)
{
    WeeklyTotal[w-1] = WeeklyTotal[w-1] + (int)data.Rows[i]["week" + w];
}
```

or

```
int[] WeeklyTotal = new int[53];
for (int w = 0; w < 53; w++)
{
    WeeklyTotal[w] = WeeklyTotal[w] + (int)data.Rows[i]["week" + (w+1)];
}
```